# how to find text before and after given words and output into different text files?

Tags: python, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file like this:

> ...
>   NAME : *name-1*
>   ...
>   NAME : *name-2*
>   ...
>   ...
>   ...
>   NAME : *name-n*
>   ...

I want output text files like this:

> name_1.txt : NAME : *name-1* ...
>   name_2.txt : NAME : *name-2* ...
>   ...
>   name_n.txt : NAME : *name-n* ...

I have the basic knowledge of grep, sed, awk, shell scripting, python.

Comment: Cool. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

> Solution:

```
awk '{x=gensub("-","_","g",$3)".txt"; print x" : " $0}' names.csv
name_1.txt : NAME : name-1
name_2.txt : NAME : name-2
```

`**gensub**` will do the trick here.
Please read the strings functions from following link, it should really help you. [string functions in awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for gensub().

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

`sed "s/\(.*\)\(name-.*\)/echo '\1 \2' > \2.txt/;s/-/_/2e" input-file`

- Turn line `NAME : name-2` into `echo "NAME : name-2" > name-2.txt`
- Then replace the second `-` with `_` yielding `echo "NAME : name-2" > name_2.txt`
- `e` have the shell run the command constructed in the pattern buffer.

This outputs blank lines to stdout, but creates a file for each matching line.

This depends on the file having nothing but lines matching this format... but you can expand the gist here to skip other lines with `n`.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '$1=="NAME"{f=$NF".txt"; print > f; close(f)}' file
```

which gives

```
$ head nam*
==> name-1.txt <==
NAME : name-1

==> name-2.txt <==
NAME : name-2

==> name-n.txt <==
NAME : name-n
```